# Is there any issue sharing class member on either both of doInBackground and onPostExecute of AsyncTask of android?

Tags: class, android-asynctask, share, member

```
The following is my example code.

private class PostLikes extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Void> {
 String type_id, msg;

 @Override
 protected Void doInBackground(Integer... params) {
//....
//....
  type_id = jsonobject2.getString("type_id");
  msg = jsonobject2.getString("msg");
  return null;
 }

 @Override
 protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
  if (type_id.equals("1")) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  } else {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
 }

}
```

The standard way of using AsyncTask is to make doInBackground function return some result of the background thread to onPostExecute function. 
That code is working well but I want to know whether any issue exist in the above code.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you are OK with how this is set up. Your member variables `type_id` and `msg` are referenced from `onPostExecute()` like any other member variables. `doInBackground()` will have completed by the time `onPostExecute()` run, so there will not be a threading conflict.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I also think it is better than using complicating parameter in case returning value is the multi array(String, int ,boolean). But I can't find out the example code like this on here.

Comment: i want to know your opinion.

Comment: Technically, the documentation states that The result of the background computation is passed to `onPostExecute()`. So, that is the pattern. The question is what is readable and maintainable - constructing a one-time use structure just to satisfy the pattern or to use the member variables? I think either way, but I am sure opinions would vary.